# configuring opencv 2.3.1 with bloodshed dev c++ IDE (4.9.9.2)

Tags: opencv, installation, dev-c++

I have to make a webcam based eye tracking project, and for that i need to test my thesis of blurring,then thresholding then eroding and then edge detection and then Hough's Circle detection.. which is i know very rookish or won't even work I wanna try out what i originally thought myself before i start copying algo's off the research papers.
But first and foremost,i just can't seem to setup opencv2.0.0a or the 2.3.1 version
its been 4 days, i have posted my query on the opencv's sourceforge forum, in the yahoo group of opencv [though there some guys helped, but that also didn't solve the problem]
All the other guides are for 2.x but not 2.3 or for visual studio, including all that talk about .sln files which don't work with Dev C++, so i never read them.

a few things i clearly know: dev c++ uses MinGW

I did the following probably more then 10 times, trying out little different variations [like instead of -lcxcore200, i put -llibcxcore200, and so on, or changing the include path, or

**For OpenCV 2.0.0a:**

installed the .exe, which also set a PATH variable 
Then in DEV C++:

i went to Tools->Compilers->Compiler set to configure
clicked on that little green add button
named the compiler OpenCV

**in the commands for compiler:**
-L"C:\OpenCV2.0\lib" -lcxcore200 -lcv200 -lcvaux200 -lhighgui200 -lml200
[also tried out, as previously mentioned, -llib suffix]

**for linker commandline commands:**
-lcxcore200 -lcv200 -lcvaux200 -lhighgui200 -lml200

**C Inncludes path:**
C:\OpenCV2.0\include\opencv

**Libraries:**
C:\OpenCV2.0\lib

**Binaries:**
C:\OpenCV2.0\bin

Then,I opened contour.c from C:\OpenCV2.0\samples
got 25 errors. Actually the main two must have spawned the rest. They were:

C:\opencv\samples\c\contours.c:1:39: opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h: No such file or directory
C:\opencv\samples\c\contours.c:2:39: opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp: No such file or directory

Then from here, http://programing-tutorial.blogspot.com/2009/10/linking-opencv-library-in-devc.html, 
this guy Aeronaut's second comment seemed something totally new in 4 days, and even though i implemented it, the addition of **|| _*MINGW32*_** to **#if _*GNUC*_ >= 4** making it **#if _*GNUC*_ >= 4 || _*MINGW32*_** didn't help also. Same errors. I'm just not getting it.

I tried out the LEA code from Sourceforge, it was so simple. Just added the dependencies in the Netbeans IDE to my project, and it ran, though i was slow, (for which i'm migrating to OpenCV here).
Here i haven't cracked anything in 4 days and that is frustrating me.

Answer (score 0):

check the openCV folder. In newer relases there are builds for varius tipes of OS. ( if i remeber rightly it is a build folder) and include lib and bin from flder with Your data architecture  on it.